# RhinoMock - Use a real object, but stub a single method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I'm writing a unit test against an MVC Controller that has a dependency on `IFoo`.  `Foo` (the implementation) has one method I'd like to stub, but I want to leave the other intact.  How can I set this up using `RhinoMock`?

`Foo` has several dependencies that I'd prefer *not* to mock to save writing additional lines of code and cluttering my test.

### Foo :

```
public interface IFoo{
    int Method1();
    int Method2();
}

public class Foo : IFoo{
   //lot's of dependencies
   public Foo(IBar bar, IBaz baz, IStackOverflow so){}
}
```

### Test:

```
[Test]
public void What_I_Have_So_Far(){
    //arrange
    //load the real IFoo from Ninject (DI)
    var mockFoo = new Ninject.Kernel(new MyExampleModule())
                    .Get<IFoo>();

    //I want this test to use the real Method1, but not Method2
    //so stub Method2
    mockFoo
       .Stub(x => x.Method2()) //<---- blows up here
       .Returns(42);

    //act
    var controllerUnderTest = new Controller(mockFoo);
```

### Error:

Using this approach, RhinoMock throws an Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The object 'MyApplication.MyExampleModule' is not a mocked object.

### Question:

How can I stub `method2`?

I know I could create `IFoo` as a mock via `MockRepository.GenerateMock`, but then'd I'd have to copy the real implementation of `Method1`.

---

### Update:

Both Brad and Jimmy's solution seam to work equally well, I picked Brad's only because it was less code to write.

However, after researching this a bit further, it looks like what I need is an AutoMocker.  There seams to be one for [StructureMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761090/how-structure-map-automocker-inject-works) and [Moq](https://github.com/tkellogg/Moq.AutoMocker), but not RhinoMocks: https://github.com/RhinoMocks/RhinoMocks/issues/3

Comment: Great question. Could you not `GenerateMock` of the implementation class (`Foo`)? You wouldn't have to copy the real implementation - it would be the actual class, but then RhinoMocks could set up `method2`. Either that or mark the method as `virtual`?

Comment: @RowanFreeman - I've been experimenting with both `GenerateMock` and `GeneratePartialMock`, but if I mock the class `Foo` RhinoMock blows up because `Foo` does not have a parameter-less constructor.  So this leads to the question: **How to get RhinoMocks to play nice with DI**, specifically Ninject?

Comment: What about `TestFoo : Foo` and using `public new Int32 Method2()` to hide the original implementation (then, obviously, wire up with ninject).

Comment: @BradChristie - In principle this would work (it won't work with `new`, the original method has to be `virtual` and the `TestFoo` will have to `override` it).  But this bothers me as it seems like I'm writing more code than I need it.  That and I'm not excited to need to mark all of my methods virtual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it the other way around. Create mocked `IFoo` and redirect *some* calls to real `IFoo` (this has to be done via `WhenCalled` extension):

```
var realFoo = new Ninject.Kernel(new MyExampleModule()).Get<IFoo>();
var mockFoo = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFoo>();

mockFoo.Stub(f => f.Method2()).Return(42);
mockFoo.Stub(f => f.Method1())
   .WhenCalled(invocation =>
   {
       invocation.ReturnValue = realFoo.Method2();
   })
   .Return(whateverValue);
```

The final `Return` is required even though we override it few lines before. Otherwise Rhino will throw exception.

Comment: This solution should work, but it still hides bad design. It looks that IFoo should be divided to two interfaces. IFoo is probably breaking [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: @PetrBehenský: you are most likely right, although its hard to be certain basing on `Method1` and `Method2` names. OP tries to do partial mock without overridable methods, and as far as I know this is the only viable solution to this problem (apart from redesign).

Comment: @PetrBehenský - I disagree with your comment about Single Responsibility.  Granted, this is an overly simplified example, but it's perfectly fine for an interface to have more than one method and not break Single Responsibility.  In my case IFoo an Adapter that serializes / deserializes payloads, so it's one responsibility is to convert between a 3rd party object and my domain object. I think it would be overkill to split these two out to ISerializeFoo and IDeserializeFoo.

Comment: @jimmy_keen - Is there an automated way to build this up or an add-on framework to do this?  Ideally I would do something like `mockFoo.AutoMock(realFoo)` and that would wire up the stub for `Method1` and then I could just restub `method2`.

Comment: @PhilipPittle: not that I'm aware of. [Other frameworks, yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924445/fakeiteasy-proxy-methods-calls-to-real-implementation), RhinoMocks not so much.

Comment: @Phillip There is no problem having several methods in interface, but in my opinion that it is not correct when one of these (public) methods is dependent on another method on same interface.

Answer (score 1):

With the least amount of "invasive" effort necessary, I would consider using the adapter pattern. So, we have our original interface and concrete class:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Method1();
    void Method2();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am Method1 of Foo");
    }
    public void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am Method2 of Foo");
    }
}
```

And a single implementation used for unit tests:

```
public class FooAdapter : IFoo
{
    private readonly IFoo foo;

    public FooAdapter(IFoo foo)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        this.foo.Method1();
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am Method2 of FooAdapter");
    }
}
```

That class could be local to the unit test class and simply defined as:

```
IFoo foo = new FooAdapter(kernel.Get<IFoo>());
```

I agree with you, changing your base code to satisfy unit tests is not the right path. Unit tests should sit atop casually and never be reverse plumbed into the code they're targeting.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but I could see this being a real pain to write and maintain.  Unless there was a framework / VS plug-in to auto generate the wrapper/adapter.

Answer (score 1):

> However, after researching this a bit further, it looks like what I
>   need is an AutoMocker. There seams to be one for StructureMap and Moq,
>   but not RhinoMocks: https://github.com/RhinoMocks/RhinoMocks/issues/3

I haven't looked into it much, but I know of the AutoMock project on CodePlex. Maybe that's the answer?

**Features**

- Creates mocks/stubs on the fly for any class under test that depends on a set of dependencies through constructor based dependency injection.
- Currently supports RhinoMocks.

https://automock.codeplex.com/

Comment: I looked through the examples a bit, and I think this is actually exactly what you want. Do let me know if it works out!